# Pagination in Java

Tags: java, pagination

I wrote paging logic:

My requirement: total elements to display:100 per page,if i click next it should display next 100 records,if i click previous 100 records.

Initial varaible values:

- showFrom:1,
- showTo:100
- max elements:depends on size of data.
- pageSize:100.

Code:

```
if(paging.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Next")){
  paging.setTotalRec(availableList.size());
  showFrom = (showTo + 1);
  showTo = showFrom + 100- 1;
  if(showTo >= paging.getTotalRec())
    showTo = paging.getTotalRec();
  paging.setShowFrom(showFrom);
  paging.setShowTo(showTo);
}

else if(paging.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Previous")){
  showTo = showFrom - 1;
  showFrom = (showFrom - 100);
  paging.setShowTo(showTo);
  paging.setShowFrom(showFrom);
  paging.setTotalRec(availableList.size());
}
```

Here i can remove and add the elements to the existing data.above code works fine if i add and remove few elements.but if i remove or add 100 elements at a time counts are not displaying properly above code works fine if i add and remove few elements.

Comment: To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Comment: What exactly `paging` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to improve:

- replace "magic" value of 100 with `final int PAGE_SIZE = 100;`
- factor out redundant code.

> ```
>   paging.setShowTo(showTo);
>   paging.setShowFrom(showFrom);
>   paging.setTotalRec(availableList.size());
> ```

to outside of if/else to make your logic clearer

- Ensure that previous >= 0 and next <= number of records

**Edit:**

```
final int PAGE_SIZE = 100;
int numberOfPages = -1;
int currentPage = -1;

public void initializeVariables(){
  paging.setTotalRec(availableList.size());
  showFrom = 1; 
  showTo = PAGE_SIZE;
  //keep track of how many pages there should be
  numberOfPages = paging.getTotalRec()/PAGE_SIZE;
  currentPage = 1;
}

public void handlePagingAction(){
  if(paging.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Next")){
     if(currentPage < numberOfPages){
        ++currentPage;
     }
  }else if(paging.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Previous")){
     if(currentPage > 1){       
       --currentPage;
     }
  }      

  showFrom = (currentPage - 1) * PAGE_SIZE + 1;
  if(showFrom < 0){
    showFrom = 0
  }

  showTo = currentPage * PAGE_SIZE;
  if(showTo >= paging.getTotalRec()){
    showTo = paging.getTotalRec();
  }     

  paging.setShowTo(showTo);
  paging.setShowFrom(showFrom);
}
```

Comment: brain:Can you modify that code please,i dont understand what i am missing.

Comment: Brain:next is working fine,Previous logic failed.intially 1 to 100 of 288.101 to 200,201 to 288.if i click previous it is showing 101 to 188.instead of 200.

Comment: Brain: total count not always multiple of 100's.in my previous comment total count is 288.

Comment: Brain:I am calling this method from Ajax,My pagination starts with 0.So initially currentPage is 0,if i click next i am incrementing,if i do previous i am decrementing the currentPage value.page size always 100,no of pages depends on adding and removing the elements.do i need to take any special instructions.

Comment: @user569125 Adjust the variables that use `currentPage` accordingly. ex) currentPage > 0 instead of currentPage > 1, currentPage instead of old (currentPage - 1), (currentPage + 1) instead of old currentPage

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- In the line `showTo = showFrom + 100- 1;`, why minus 1?
- If showTo is equal to paging.getTotalRec(), the next time you press Next, showFrom will be over paging.getTotalRec()
- In the Previous part, tests to prevent going below 0 are missing

Hope this helps...