# Pagination Without Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, jpa, web

I am creating a web application using Spring MVC and my database isn't supported by Spring Data. How can I add pagination without using Spring Data. My application has a table which list out objects retrieved via a service which has the ability to retrieve paginated results(i am able to pass in  the page and result size). The problem comes when the user searches by date range or any other search where parameters are placed in the url. I cannot figure out a way to generate the correct url for the "next" and "prev" links.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821361/how-to-write-pagination-logic

Answer (score 0):

If your database isn't supported by Spring Data you can reuse class PageImpl to wrap your result and not use page data in queries, just wrap your search result.

```
List<T> content = your result set;
Pageable pageable= new PageRequest(int page, int size);
long total = cound found elements;
PageImpl pager = new PageImpl(content,pageable,cound );
```

in this case, you just reuse class and you don't need to work with calculation.
class PageRequest has `previous(), next()` methods, so you don't need to calculate it.

If you don't want to have spring data as dependency you can just copy and put into your project page classes that you need.

Comment: What i am confused on is how to access the next and prev in the jsp. Ok so to explain more fully. I have a controller method which handles the default landing, gets information from the db and i can add that to the model to e displayed in the jsp. In my table i have a form for date range and a form for searching. If the user were to select a date range than it makes a request like this /baseurl/daterange?from=somevalue&to=somevalue. So in order to get the next page of results the user would click the next link.Problem is that I cannot find a way to append the current page param to existing url

Comment: The service methods I am calling look something like this service.getObjectsByDateRange(from, to, skip, limit) 
skip meaning the amount of data to skip and limit being the amount returned

Comment: and you can't change this service?  Just example - you have 111 elements , page size = 5 , current page = 10 , amount of page 111 / 5 = 13 pages.  In your case "from, to, skip, limit" what is what ?

Comment: " it makes a request like this /baseurl/daterange?from=somevalue&to=somevalue. So in order to get the next page of results the user would click the next link.Problem is that I cannot find a way to append the current page param to existing url " -- how you know then current page? -- in case with 111 element you have : from=50 (element ) to = 55 (element). You know page size and from , so you can calculate current page, next page and prev page

Comment: check PageImpl source . methods getTotalPages , and PageImpl's constructor , you can find logic that you need and copy it if you can't use PageImpl class

Comment: Yeah i can calculate the current page. I guess I am having trouble understanding how to connect this with that is being displayed in the jsp. Am i supposed to, within my controller, add that PageImp object to the model. If the user would like to go to the next page what would he click? A link? And if so how should that url look?

Comment: My original thought was to have a next link, something like href="?currentPage=${currentPage}" I was hopping for the user to click the link then currentpage would be appended to the url so it would end up looking like this "/project/objects/daterange?from=value&to=value&currentPage=value" My controller method would take the 3 parameters in as arguments and would add the paginated result to the model(i already have a method in my service to take in those params and give back the paginated results). Am i going about this all wrong? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Can you show or send by mail jsp page or eeb page and controller?or just relevant code to pager?i can show how you can do this in 3 4 hours